# Getting domain from subdomain

Tags: c#, .net, url, subdomain

I get url as

> http://orders.mealsandyou.com/default.php

i dont want to use string functions to use it to get the main domain ie

> mealsandyou.com

is there any function in c# to do that, UrilAuthority and all gives subdomain too...

Suggestions welcome, not workarounds

Comment: "i dont want to use string functions" - why?

Comment: @MitchWheat I prefer not to use workarounds/kludge. .NET is very powerful framework, it should/must have something for this too

Comment: If there's is this kind of function in .NET libraries they will still return domains as string. I cant understand what do you mean in: "i  dont want to use string functions to use it to get the main domail"

Comment: since when is parsing using string functions a kludge?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a general fashion as its different for different tlds, eg mealsandyou.com and mealsandyou.co.uk.

Comment: @MitchWheat dnt take me as a wrong, that will be the last thing I want to use, I prefer it that way, you are taking me wrong

Comment: I assume what he's looking for is a uri.subdomain and uri.domain on the URI object. (except it isn't there!)

Comment: The only constant part of the domain string is the TLD. technically everything else is a subdomain, so its subjective as to which part is the bit you're insterested as being the domain name rather than the subdomain.

Comment: @MitchWheat is its nothing defined in library, we have to use string then.. but I'm looking for more options to achieve this(if any)

Comment: @JonEgerton, what I'm trying to do is if this subdomain is entered in the browser without any querystring then it should redirect it to TLD

Comment: But the TLD is `com`, which is probably not what you want, you want one below the TLD. But with `mealsandyou.co.uk` you probably want 2 below the TLD. While it was once considered bad practice to have a 2-letter or less domain for anything other than a NIC, such sensible policies have been frowned on for some time, so `u.tv` and `o2.ie` are examples of how you can't use that as a guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract domain name from URL in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120793/extract-domain-name-from-url-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @daryal its not duplicate, I want it from subdomain. and if subdomain is not present then it will just give that only

Comment: @JonEgerton please post your ans, I will select it as the right ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only constant part of the domain string is the TLD. The TLD is the very last bit of the domain string, eg .com, .net, .uk etc. Everything else under that depends on the particular TLD for its position (so you can't assume the next to last part is the "domain name" as, for .co.uk it would be .co.

In any case I think you're taking the wrong approach. URL rewriting is far more suited to this sort of thing. Have a read of this: learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 3):

.Net doesn't provide a built-in feature to extract specific parts from `Uri.Host`. You will have to use string manipulation or a regular expression yourself.

Comment: so till now we dont have anything like that.. hmm.. that a pain