# How to Exclude Subdomain From URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting domain from subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259912/getting-domain-from-subdomain)

I have a query in which i am fetching Hostname from URI.

```
Eg. if i have http://www.google.com/abc/abcd/ade/a.htm

then the url is "www.google.com" 

var uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/abc/abcd/ade/a.htm");
uri.Host // i get www.google.com

But when i try it with Subdomain i want to exclude the Subdomain from the url

var uri = new Uri("http://mail.google.com/abc/abcd/ade/a.htm");
    uri.Host // i get mail.google.com

I want only google.com
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear - there is no technical difference between "www." and "mail." - both are sub-domains...

Comment: Duplicate in a sense - "there is no helper functions in .Net to do that".